# Which one is correct: I find/found/have found something interesting

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, time

If I noticed that something was interesting (in the past), and I still think it is so, should I say:

> I find (?) your paper interesting.

Or which tense (*find/found/have found*) should I  use?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. In your question, please add what you think the correct way of saying it is and why, that way it will be easier for the answerers to guide you (if necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would say

> I find your paper interesting.

using the present simple tense.

> We use the present simple to describe general actions, events, and states when we have no reason to think of them as being in any way temporary or limited in time.

Parrott, M. (2000). *Grammar for English Language Teachers.* Cambridge: Cambridge University Presss.